# Pass files from input-element to plupload (Add folder)

Tags: javascript, jquery, plupload

I want to upload all files of a folder. Since *plupload* does not offer this functionality, I have an input like this

```
<input type="file" name="files[]" id="files" multiple directory="" webkitdirectory="" mozdirectory="">
```

that stores all files out of a chosen folder. I now want to load these to my uploader

```
uploader = new plupload.Uploader({});
```

When I try to do so like

```
$('#files').change(function (){
    if ($(this).prop('files').length > 0)
    {
        uploader.addFile($('#files').prop('files')[0]);
    }
});
```

it results in

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'processing' of null
```

at

```
uploader.start();
```

How can I pass file references from my input-element to the plupload-Uploader?

Comment: Are you trying to upload all files in the selected folder?

Comment: @JenuelGanawed yes, I select a folder and then upload all files that it contains. The point here is that I do not want to select the files themselves and plupload does not offer webkitdirectory support

Answer (score 0):

I got a workaround here. One set the files of the plupload input-element via jQuery and trigger onChange to make it work.

```
$('#html5_plupload-HASH').prop('files', $('#files').get(0).files).change();
```

I also discovered that plupload actually offers support for webkitdirectory in version 2 according to their [list of supported features](https://www.plupload.com/docs/v2/Required-Features). There is a parameter called `select_folder` but I could not get it to work by now.

It is also possible to just find the input-element in `plupload.full(.min).js` and add webkitdirectory attribute.